# javascript minus count when wrong key pressed?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a game and I need to make a counting function to minus 1 attempt every time a wrong key is pressed.

Here's my code so far:

```
var names = ["Adam Red", "Bob Green", "Chris Blue"];
var nameChosen = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
var nameSplit = nameChosen.split("");
var updated = [];
var attempt = nameChosen.length - 2;

function display(char) {
    //replace each of the letters with underscore and space with dash
    char = char || '_';   // set to default when no char given
    var nameDisplayed = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nameSplit.length; i++) {
        if (updated[i] || (char.toLowerCase() === nameSplit[i].toLowerCase())) {
            nameDisplayed += nameSplit[i];
            updated[i] = true;
        }
        else if (nameSplit[i] == " ") {
            nameDisplayed += "- ";
        } 
        else {
            nameDisplayed += "_ ";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameDisplayed;
}

//get key pressed by user
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    display(charStr); // call when typing
});

display(); // call onload
```

I know I need to put `attempt--` somewhere in the loop, but I could only make it minus all the length of the letters when a wrong key is pressed.

For example: if the chosen name is `Adam Red` and `key z` is pressed, then instead of `attempt = attempt - 1`, it gives me `attempt = attempt - 7` (total number of the letters in Adam Red).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written another code part to do the same job. I have tried to use some `ES6` codes like `lambda functions`.

The code i wrote can do things below;

- when key pressed checks the letter is in the name
- all the keys are allowed to pressed one time only
- shows attempt count
- says **You Win!** when you find the name
- says **You Lost!** if you can't find before the attempt counter comes to zero

**The code is like this:**

```js
let names = ["Adam Red", "Bob Green", "Chris Blue"];
let nameChosen = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
let nameSplit = nameChosen.split("");
let attempt = nameChosen.length - 2;

const chosenName = [];
const letterTried = [];

let checkWin = () => chosenName.filter(val => val.isLetter).map(val => val.isFound).reduce((a, b) => a && b, true);
let toText = () => chosenName.map(val => val.valueFound).reduce((a, b) => a + " " + b, "");

nameSplit.forEach(function(val, i) {
  chosenName.push({
    isLetter: val.match(/[a-z]/i) ? true : false,
    isFound: false,
    value: val,
    valueFound: val == " " ? "-" : "_",
    index: i
  });
});

function check(charStr) {
  if (letterTried.includes(charStr))
    return false;

  letterTried.push(charStr);

  chosenName.filter(val => !val.isFound && val.isLetter).forEach(function(val, i) {
    if (charStr.toLowerCase() === val.value.toLowerCase()) {
      val.valueFound = val.value;
      val.isFound = true;
    }
  });

  if (!chosenName.map(val => val.value.toLowerCase()).includes(charStr.toLowerCase()))
    attempt--;
}

//get key pressed by user
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
  var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

  check(charStr);
  document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = toText();
  document.getElementById("attempt").innerHTML = attempt;

  if (checkWin())
    document.getElementById("attempt").innerHTML = "You Win!";

  if (attempt <= 0)
    document.getElementById("attempt").innerHTML = "You Lost!";
});

document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = toText();
document.getElementById("attempt").innerHTML = attempt;
```

```html
<div id="nameDisplay"></div>
Attempts: <span id="attempt"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you Gurkanat for your suggestion. I'll try it and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Hi Gurkanat. I could use your code to make sure keys are allowed to be pressed one time. However, due to the fact that I use loops to replace the letters with underscores and spaces with dashes, I cannot use the checkWin function. Can you help me with that? Also, if I get the checkLose right, how can I stop the use from pressing more new keys?

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like you have access to `nameChosen` and `attempt` globally. If it is indeed the case you can then update your event listener that way:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

    if (nameChosen.includes(charStr))
        display(charStr); // call when typing
    else 
        attempts--;
});
```

Basically the change I made was to add a check using the method [`String.includes()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) to verify if the chosen name contains the character string before updating the UI. Also you may want to add some UI feedback for the player to know his number of attempts is going down.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, Nguele. Btw, how would you make sure a key is only used one time or print out the wrong key one time? I can only print them all out, as long as the user presses a key.

Answer (score 1):

given solution uses includes which is part of ES6. If you want to support older browsers as well here is solution using indexOf.

```
var updated = new Array(nameSplit.length).join('_');
function display(char) {
    //replace each of the letters with underscore and space with dash
    char = char || '_';   // set to default when no char given
    var nameDisplayed = [];

    var indexAt = nameSplit.indexOf(char);
    if(indexAt !== -1) {
        // to avoid in next search
        nameSplit[indexAt] = null;
        updated[indexAt] = char;
    } else {
        attempt--;
    }
    document.getElementById("nameDisplay").innerHTML = nameDisplayed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way. Do you know how to make sure a key is allowed to pressed one time only?

Comment: In that case this solution will not work. You need to use indexOf in loop to find all occurrence using  
var indexes = [], i = -1;
    while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
        indexes.push(i);
    }

You can check if pressed key exists in updated array. If it is present then key is already pressed, in this case instead of attempt-- simply return from function.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what your code does. Is there a way I can store all the value/char of pressed keys in an array so I can check it whenever a key is pressed?